# Delete dynamically load iterm from sql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a VERY basic cart for a project for school. The items are dynamically loaded from a DB and I would like to be able to Dynamically delete them upon POST but I cannot figure out how to dynamically keep track of the name attribute so I can you post in my delete query.

```
 <?php 

    require_once('dbconnection.php');
    session_start(); //starts seesion for username this needs to be at the top of every page.

    // head
    $page_title = 'Search Results';
    require_once('layouts/head.php');

    //Handles deleted items
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $remove = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE cart.* FROM `cart` 
                                    inner join 'product'
                                    on product.id = cart.product_id
                                    WHERE `product_name` = ?");

        //TODO:get the post for the specific item name and add to bind method
        $remove->bind_param('s', $name);

        if(!$remove->execute() === true) {
            echo $mysqli->error;               
        }
    }


 <body>
    <!-- inlclude nav -->
    <?php require_once('layouts/nav.php'); ?>

    <main role="main">

      <!-- include jumbo -->
      <?php 
        require_once('layouts/jumbotron.php');
      ?>

      <div class="container">
        <!-- Container Heading -->
        <h1>
            <?php 
                if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                    echo $_SESSION['username']. "'s  Cart <hr>" ;

                }
                else{
                    echo "Your Cart <hr>";
                }
            ?>

        </h1>




        <ul class="panel panel-default">

            <?php 

                global $globalArr;
                $sum = 0;

                // TODO: check if user has an active cart if they do then display itemes
                $sql = "SELECT user.username, status.status_type, product.product_name, product.price, product.id  from cart
                        inner join status
                        on status.id = cart.status_id
                        inner join user
                        on user.id = cart.user_id
                        inner join product
                        on product.id = cart.product_id
                        WHERE status_type = 'purchased' AND username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                // TODO: add a remove from cart
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        echo "<h3>" .$result->num_rows. " item(s) in cart </h3>";


                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                            echo '<from action="cart.php" method="post"><li class="list-group-item" name="'.$row["product_name"].'">'
                                    .$row["product_name"]. ' - $'. $row["price"].'  <button class="badge" type="submit" name="delete"> X </button> </li></form>';
                            array_push($globalArr, $row["product_name"]);
                            $sum += floatval($row['price']);

                        }//END WHILE

                        echo $sum;

                } else {

                    echo "<h3> YOUR CART IS EMPTY! BUY SOMETHING! </h3>";
                }

                echo '</div>'


            ?>


        </ul>
        <hr>
      </div> 
      <!-- /container -->

    </main>

<!-- include footer -->
      <?php 
        require_once('layouts/footer.php');
      ?>

    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
      <?php 
        require_once('layouts/scripts.php');
      ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I think my post is pretty clear but I was asked to add more details so here are some more really cool details that might help. I am having a very hard time with this problem. Any solution that you may have would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to be so awesome and not flame my post. Thanks again!

Comment: It **sounds** like you'd simply need to set `$name` equal to `$_POST['product_id']`, and then ensure you make use of a POST request that contains the relevant attribute. For example, you could use something like: `<form> <input name="product_id"> ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your problem, but if you want to send the name of the cart item to delete through a POST request, you can use [hidden inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden) for this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<from action="cart.php" method="post">'
        .'<li class="list-group-item" name="'.$row["product_name"].'">'
            .$row["product_name"]. ' - $'. $row["price"]
            .'<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$row["product_name"].'">'
            .'<button class="badge" type="submit" name="delete"> X </button>'
        .'</li>'
    .'</form>';
    array_push($globalArr, $row["product_name"]);
    $sum += floatval($row['price']);
}//END WHILE
```

And then use `$remove->bind_param('s', $_POST['item_name']);`

Hope this helps